# Document contains at least one immense term - Solr indexing error

Tags: pdf, solr, nutch

I am facing this issue with one of my PDF files which I presume which fails to be indexed into Solr due to its large file size. I have seen replies online mostly advising to change the field type of ***'content' to 'text_general'***, which I have been using all the while but this particular PDF still cannot be indexed.

**Error produced:**

Exception writing document id abc.com/files/hugepdf.pdf to the index; possible analysis error: ***Document contains at least one immense term in field="content" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766)***, all of which were skipped.  Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms.  The prefix of the first immense term is: '[66, 65, 82, 73, 78, 71, 32, 71, 76, 79, 66, 65, 76, 32, 79, 80, 80, 79, 82, 84, 85, 78, 73, 84, 73, 69, 83, 32, 85, 77]...', original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 110482. Perhaps the document has an indexed string field (solr.StrField) which is too large

**Current schema of 'text_general'**

```
  <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.TruncateTokenFilterFactory" prefixLength="100"/> 
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="multiterm">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Do note that I added a 'TruncateTokenFilterFactory' filter which helped to solve the issues with most large PDF files. However this PDF is an exception.

**Questions**

1. What is the way to make it possible to successfully index such PDFs?
2. On indexing failure, all the indexes will not be added into Solr (which wastes all effort which takes a long time (a couple of hours) due to 1 PDF file which exceeds max size. Is there any way around this to add only successful indexes while only rejecting specific indexes?

Answer (score 0):

indexing pdf content is a known 'nightmare'. You will never get 100% correct text extraction. I suspect your issue here is that the extraction is not working for that pdf, and its returning a huge pile of garbage. Truncating that is not the best approach, ignoring it would be better. Using 'text_general' would not help at all.

Some general guidelines would be:

1. do the text extraction out of solr. Yes it is handy to use Solr Cell, but with real world pdf and volumes, the worst case is the process will hang (that is worse than dying). Do it out of solr, in multiple threads, this will speed it up and make Solr more reliable (less stress on it).
2. use a fallback library. You are probabaly usuing PDFBox (if you are using Cell). If that fails to extract some file, use a second library (there are several)

Comment: PDFBox itself has no fixed limit on PDF size. So one might still get text outside of Solr by using the ExtractText command line tool.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if there is anyway to detect any PDFs > 32766 in size so that I can then specify those in my reg-urlfilter.txt. Is there such a way?